# How to make changes to a df based on the name of the files in R?

Tags: r, database, filenames

So I want to make changes to dataframes based on the names of the files. So if there is "adjusted" in the filename of a dataframe, I want to add a variable named "adjusted". I guess it would look similar to what I did below, but obviously "filenames" does not exist, but I couldn't figure out if there exists any function in R that would let me do it this way.

```
files = list.files(pattern="*.dta") 
dflist <- list()

for (i in 1:length(files)){
  dflist[[i]] <- read.dta13(files[i], nonint.factors = TRUE)

   if("adjusted" %in% filenames(dflist[[i]])){             
    dflist[[i]]$adjusted <- "yes"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were really close with your original function. Just replace `%in%` with the `grepl()` function and reference your `files` list. Try this:

```
files = list.files(pattern="*.dta") 
dflist <- list()

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  dflist[[i]] <- read.dta13(files[[i]], nonint.factors = TRUE)

  if(grepl("adjusted", files[[i]]) == TRUE) {
    dflist[[i]]$adjusted <- "yes"
  }
}
```